# parent div height is not applying for child div

Tags: html, css, styles, height

I have created a html stuff which has a parent div named as `parent-portlet`. `parent-portlet` class is having `height` set to 40%. The html is renedering correctly but the issue is that the child div (`child-fluid`) height is not getting applied to that of the parent div (`parent-portlet`).

Can anyone please tell me some solution for this

My code is as given below

**[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/fsZtvtjRmXHVCR3tq9q5?p=preview)**

**Html**

```
  <div class="parent-portlet">
    <div class="child-fluid">
      <div class="box">
        <div class="box-header well">
          <h2><i class="icon-bullhorn"></i> Alerts</h2>
        </div>
        <div class="portlet-content box-content alerts">
          <div class="alert alert-error">
            <strong>Oh snap!</strong> Change a few things up and try submitting again.
          </div>
          <div class="alert alert-success">
            <strong>Well done!</strong> You successfully read this important alert message.
          </div>
          <div class="alert alert-info">
            <strong>Heads up!</strong> This alert needs your attention, but it's not super important.
          </div>
          <div class="alert alert-block ">
            <h4 class="alert-heading">Warning!</h4>
            <p>Best check yo self, you're not looking too good. Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue. Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur et.</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

**css**

```
.parent-portlet { 
  height: 40%;
}

.portlet-content {
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.child-fluid {
  height: inherit;
}
```

Comment: This may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/a/31728799/3597276

Comment: can you give me a updated plunker

Comment: Sorry Alex, on my mobile and plunkr not accessible. Will try again when back at my desktop. But bottom line, when using percentage heights, you need to specify a height for all parent elements, up to and including the root element. Make sure you have `html, body { height: 100%; }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.parent-portlet` inherits 40% of its parent which does not have height. So you can give `height:100%` to `html` and `body` and then set `overflow-y: auto;` on `.parent-portlet`

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/HdliSz3Iw1fJJPIT5Ygj?p=preview)

An element has `height:auto;` by default if you don't specify height for it, it won't inherit `height` from its parent. In addition, according to [w3c](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#the-height-property):

> **Height : Percentage Value**
>
> The percentage was always calculated with respect to the content box
>   of the parent element.

**Edited after comment:**

You have give `height: 100%;` and `overflow-y: auto;` to `.child-fluid`

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/ooLXnlLaNwlJnxaKmGRZ?p=preview)

**OP desire situation:**

> I need to have a fixed `.box-header` on top of `.box` and scrolling
>   `.box-content`.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/rGFrtSVxpEFW3SSudspZ?p=preview)

Comment: Thanks for your answer but the issue is that, say if .parent-portlet is having 40% height then same height should apply to .child-fluid giving scrollbar for the portlet-content

Comment: actually I want the scrollbar to come for `.child-fluid` `portlet-content`, right now it is coming for `.parent-portlet`

Comment: @AlexMan Does it fix your problem?

Comment: can you come for a [chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97701/chat-with-alireza)

Comment: I have a similar issue again, I have posted a new SO question [css for applying correctly for a bootstrap box](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34238478/css-for-applying-correctly-for-a-bootstrap-box), Can you please take a look